# Unable to see any callback when querying Neo4j from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I send a query from Node.js to Neo4j, but I do not see anything callback. The query is correctly executed but I am unable to see any information i nthe callback and log it in the console.

I think node.js executes console.log before any data has come, but I do not know how to solve it.

Node.js:

```
// Load Modules
var neo4j = require('neo4j');

// Database Connection
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase("http://neo4j:Gemitis26@localhost:7474/");

// Inizialize Query
var query = "CREATE (:Song {name:'James'})";

db.cypher(query, function(err, node){
    if(err) throw err;

    // Output node properties.
    console.log(node.data);

    // Output node id.
    console.log(node._id);
});
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\RRamos\Documents\Projects\test-neo4j>node index.js
[]
undefined
```

As I said, I check it and it is correctly created.

Comment: what happens if you try to log just the node ?

Comment: what should it return when you only CREATE and not QUERY the db?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems in your code:

1. Your Cypher query does not have a `RETURN` clause so your query response will always be an empty array (because it will never contain any result rows).
2. Your callback is expecting to wrong data structure for the response.

Try this code. It dumps out the error (if any) and the response, so that you can see the actual data structure of a response. It also uses a for-loop to iterate through the rows of data in the response and print out each `s` node's properties and its native ID. In your case, there will only be at most one result row, so the loop is not strictly necessary, but in general there can be multiple rows.

```
// Load Modules
var neo4j = require('neo4j');

// Database Connection
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase("http://neo4j:Gemitis2@localhost:7474/");

// Inizialize Query
var query = "MATCH (s:Song {name:'James'}) RETURN s";

db.cypher(query, function(err, res){

    // Dump out the err and response, to see the data structure.
    console.log("err: %j, res: %j", err, res);

    if(err) throw err;

    // Print out the data for each row in the response.
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        var s = res[i].s;
        // Output node properties.
        console.log(s.properties);

        // Output node id.
        console.log(s._id);
    }


});
```